# Write Iterator for an abstract class

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, iterator

I have made an abstract class List, and then the class DLL (doubly linked list) to inherent it. To make it work well in access sequentially data, I use Iterator. But I am stuck in it. I can make the Iterator for the class DLL, but I want to make it virtually. I mean the Iterator can work with any of the derived class of List. Below is my code. Can you guys give me some ideas how can I code the class Iterator to work with my purpose. If there some example code I would really appreciated.

```
template<typename T>
class List {
public:
    class Iterator;
    virtual ~List() = default;
    virtual void push_back(T value) = 0;
    virtual void push_front(T value) = 0;
    virtual Iterator begin() = 0;
    virtual Iterator end() = 0;
};
template <typename T>
class DLL : public List<T> {
public:
    class Node;
private:
    Node <T> * head;
    Node <T> * tail;
    int size;
public:
    DLL();
    ~DLL();
    void push_front(T value);
    void push_back(T value);
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();
};
```

I want the Iterator can work like this:

```
int main (){
    List<List<int>*> *ptr = new DLL<List<int>*>;
    List<int>* ptr1 = new DLL<int>;
    for (int i; i < 10; i++)
    ptr1->push_back(i);
    ptr->push_back(ptr1);
    List<List<int>*>::Iterator it = ptr->begin();
    List<int>::Iterator it1 = ptr1->begin();
}
```

and also can it work like this(?):

```
    DLL<DLL<int>*>* data = new DLL<DLL<int>*>;
    DLL<DLL<int>*>::Iterator it2 = data->begin();
```

Note: if something I wrote unclear or unaccurate please tell me. Thank you guys so much!!

I hope I can make the Iterator work well for any derived class of List.

Comment: You are basically trying to reinvent the wheel : all that is already implemented in std containers. Just access the code for std::list and its iterator.

Comment: *" I mean the Iterator can work with any of the derived class of List."* -- What does it mean to "work" in this context? __Example:__ For a doubly-linked list, decrementing an iterator is expected to be a fast operation, while it is slow for a singly-linked list. Do you plan to have your all-in-one iterator always choose the slow path for compatibility? Have you accounted for derived classes you have not envisioned?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will look it up. But by the way, I have to code it out :)

Comment: Because the iterator can't be generic enough for all kinds of "lists", you have to do some tricks to make it work. One such trick is [the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to define an alias in the base class for the child-class concrete iterator type.

Comment: On another note, why limit yourself to "lists", why not make a generic container base class? Or do what the standard library itself does: Define a specific interface implemented by all containers, but not by using an abstract base class but only through convention. And design all functions using containers to use iterators instead of the container class itself.

Comment: You've made it extremely hard for yourself with the declaration `Iterator begin()` in `List`. The C++ standard library *doesn't* have a generic `iterator` as the base of all it's iterator types

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will consider it, but it's not the point here. To more specific, I want it work well with DLL mainly.

Comment: What is your exact assignment or exercise? Please tell us in the question. Include any and all possible requirements and limitations. Perhaps you're trying to over-engineer it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have virtual class List, and have to code its derived class myself.  I wrote class DLL. In another class, called Dataset. It needs List<List<int>*>* data. But I didn't notice and changed it to DLL<DLL<int>*>*. And my Iterator is written based on class DLL. In class Dataset, I have to access the elements sequentially, so I use Iterator to access the, such as DLL<DLL<int>*>::Iterator, DLL<int>::Iterator. Just when I realize that one function of Dataset will return this->data, then I try to rewrite it like List<List<int>::Iterator, List<int>::Iterator. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So I came up with an idea like this post. My assignment don't allow use library list.

Comment: Is `List<List<int>*>* data` part of the exercise? It's really suspicious to have a pointer-to-container, let alone a pointer-to-container of pointer-to-containers. Your instructor doesn't seem to be teaching idiomatic C++

Comment: @Caleth yes, List<List<int>*>* data is a part of the exercise.

Comment: Also note that even though you can assign a `DLL<int>*` to a `List<int>*`, you can't assign a `DLL<DLL<int>*>*` to a `List<List<int>*>*`, and it would be unsound to allow it

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning `List::Iterator` by value, you will have to do some tricks to hide polymorphism inside it.

```
template <typename T>
class List<T>::Iterator {
public:
    class BaseImpl {
        virtual ~BaseImpl() {}
        virtual void advance(std::ptrdiff_t) = 0;
        virtual T& dereference() const = 0;
        virtual bool equal(BaseImpl&) const = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> clone() const = 0;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> impl;
public:
    Iterator(std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> impl) : impl(std::move(impl)) {}
    Iterator(const Iterator & other) : impl(other.impl->clone()) {}
    Iterator& operator++() { impl->advance(1); return *this; }
    Iterator& operator--() { impl->advance(-1); return *this; }
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator & lhs, const Iterator & rhs) { return lhs.impl->equal(*rhs.impl); }
    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator & lhs, const Iterator & rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
    T& operator*() { return impl->dereference(); }
};
```

You haven't shown how `DLL` works, so you'll need to fill in the members of `DLL_IteratorImpl`

```
template <typename T>
class DLL_IteratorImpl : public List<T>::Iterator::BaseImpl {
    DLL<T>::Node * node;
    friend class DLL<T>;
    DLL_IteratorImpl(DLL<T>::Node * node) : node(node) {}
public:
    void advance(std::ptrdiff_t) override;
    T& dereference() const override;
    bool equal(BaseImpl& other) const override {
        if (DLL_IteratorImpl * d_other = dynamic_cast<DLL_IteratorImpl *>(&other)) {
            return node == other->node;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<BaseImpl> clone() const override {
        return new DLL_IteratorImpl(node);
    }
};

template <typename T>
List<T>::Iterator DLL<T>::begin() { return { new DLL_IteratorImpl(head) }; }
List<T>::Iterator DLL<T>::end() { return { new DLL_IteratorImpl(tail) }; }
```

This is all *highly* unidiomatic C++, caused by the requirements imposed by the definition of `List`.

N.b. if you can use C++14 or later, use `std::make_unique` instead of `new`